# Joining multiple jsonblob rows to return a JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

My table structure is as below.

I want to return the data column but joined together as a `JSON` where `type = 1` and order by the `time` column. I used `STRING_AGG()`, but its not what I want since I need to serialize this in the other side.

```
 | id | type |data                             | time              |
 | ---|----- | ------------------------------- |-------------------|
 | 1  | 1    |[{"X":55,"Y":97}]                |2022-03-02 17:20:21|
 | 2  | 1    |[{"X":3,"Y":6},{"X":39,"Y":9}]   |2022-03-02 17:20:25|
 | 3  | 5    |[{"X":9,"Y":9},{"X":33,"Y":1}]   |2022-03-02 17:20:29|
```

Basically I need to return `[{"X":55,"Y":97},{"X":3,"Y":6},{"X":39,"Y":9}]`

Comment: im using sqlserver

Comment: What you describe has nothing to do with JOINs. Frankly, it looks like the table needs a drastic redesign. What are those values and why aren't they stored in a separate table? Or as a `geometry` type? If this is a MULTIPOINT or LINESTRING, you could use [UnionAggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/unionaggregate-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to combine the points

Comment: If you really have to deal with JSON arrays, you first need to extract the values with OPENJSON then combine the result back into a JSON string with `FOR JSON`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is data from a graph. they are read over a long period of time and we save data every one second. for every save im creating a new row. (that can have one - 20 datapoints)  . but later on , i need to get all the data points for a given type.

Comment: That doesn't change any of the comments. You can store this as a `MULTIPOINT` in a `geometry` column and even add spatial indexes if needed. If you want to keep using JSON, you'll have to parse the content and generate a new JSON string as Zhorov shows

Comment: Another *unsafe* option would be to use `STRING_AGG` with an empty separator and then replace `'][` with `,`. This can easily fail due to whitespace inconsistencies though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to parse the stored data as JSON, filter and order the returned data, and build the expected data as JSON:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 1, '[{"X":55,"Y":97}]',              CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2022-03-02T17:20:21')),
   (2, 1, '[{"X":3,"Y":6},{"X":39,"Y":9}]', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2022-03-02T17:20:25')),
   (3, 5, '[{"X":9,"Y":9},{"X":33,"Y":1}]', CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2022-03-02T17:20:29'))
) d (id, [type], data, time)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   X = CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.X')),
   Y = CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Y'))
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.data) j
WHERE d.type = 1
ORDER BY d.time, CONVERT(int, j.[key])
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[{"X":55,"Y":97},{"X":3,"Y":6},{"X":39,"Y":9}]
```

Comment: May i know what does , CONVERT(int, j.[key]) this part do ?

Comment: `OPENJSON` with default schema [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and when the parsed JSON is a JSON array, the `key` column holds a 0-based index of the element in the specified array as an nvarchar(4000) value. `CONVERT(int, j.[key])` simply returns the JSON array items in the original order.